# Removing the optical drive on my Mac Book Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, optical-drive

I have a Mac Book Pro 15" early 2011.

I have just realised that since I was never using the optical drive and was always complaining that the thing was too heavy, it would be a rich idea to remove this drive.

Would this affect anything in the computer? Risky moving part? Unplugged connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing it will not cause any problems.  Its perfectly normal to have unplugged connections; just ask anyone who has built a computer before.  I.e. Power Supply Units almost always come with more connections than you will use.  As for "Risky moving part?"  I am not sure what you mean by that.  Just make sure that you understand what to do beforehand and it should go just fine!